# Passar parametros do form para o reportview e gerar comprovante com as informações em Visual basic.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

tudo que quero é passar os parâmetros para o reportview e gerar um comprovante com as informações que estão nos campos de texto. o que não consigo é passar os parametros... tenho um exemplo em c# porém e VB.net não consigo.

Exemplo em c#

```
impressao impressao = new impressao (pesobruto.Text, pesomolhado.Text, pesofundido.Text, teor.Text, finododia.Text, precograma.Text, nomecliente.Text, totalfino.Text, total.Text, dateTimePicker4.Text, porcentagem.Text);  impressao.Show();
```

---

```
namespace ControleGastos
{
public partial class impressao : Form
{
    public impressao( string pesobruto, string pesomolhado, string pesofundido, string teor, string finododia, string precograma, string nomecliente, string totalfino, string total, string data, string porcentagem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = 
"ControleGastos.Report1.rdlc";
        Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[] p = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter[11];


        p[0] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pesobruto", pesobruto);
        p[1] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pesomolhado", pesomolhado);
        p[2] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("pesofundido", pesofundido)
;
        p[3] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("teor", teor);
        p[4] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("finododia", finododia);
        p[5] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("precograma", precograma);
        p[6] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("nomecliente", nomecliente);

        p[7] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("totalfino", totalfino);
        p[8] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("total", total);
        p[9] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("data", data);
        p[10] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("porcentagem",porcentagem);


        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(p);

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

        reportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Alguém pode me  ajudar. preciso apenas passar os parâmetros dos campos de texto para o reportview e gerar com comprovante com as informações que estão nos campos de texto....

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi a sua reportview é uma classe, não? Basta instancia-lá com um construtor com argumentos. No VB, o construtor é chamada por meio do seguinte método:

```
Public Sub New(byval arg1 as tipo1, byval arg2 as tipo2,...)

End Sub
```